# How to get the onChange() value from React Rrule Generator in TextInput field using React Admin

Tags: reactjs, recurrence, react-admin, rrule

may I know how to get the onChange() value from React Rrule Generator in TextInput field using React Admin.

The code:

[image: The code]

The output example:

[image: The output example]

The "recurrences" value returned when the user chosen:
[image: The "recurrences" value returned when the user chosen]

```
<RRuleGenerator
  onChange={(recurrences) => console.log(`${recurrences}`)}
  config={{
    repeat: ['Monthly', 'Weekly'],
    yearly: 'on the',
    monthly: 'on',
    end: ['Never', 'On date'],
    weekStartsOnSunday: true,
    hideError: true,
   }}
  />
  <TextInput label="Recurrences" source="recurrences" />
```

The react-rrule-generator I use: https://github.com/fafruch/react-rrule-generator

**Modified Code:**

```
export const RACXICreate = (props) => {
const [state, setState] = useState('')
return (<Fragment>
        <RRuleGenerator
        onChange={(rrule) => setState({ rrule })}
         value={state.rrule}
         config={{
         repeat: ['Monthly', 'Weekly'],
         yearly: 'on the',
         monthly: 'on',
         end: ['Never', 'On date'],
         weekStartsOnSunday: true,
         hideError: true,
        }}
       />
       <TextInput label="Recurrences" source="recurrences" value={state.rrule} />
     </Fragment>)}
```

But if i use this code I was able to get the value:

```
<input type="text" source="recurrences" label="Recurrences" value={state.rrule} />
```

[image]

But I mostly want to get the value in the TextInput field.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react'

  const x = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useEffect('')
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <RRuleGenerator
          onChange={val => setState(val)}
          config={{
            repeat: ['Monthly', 'Weekly'],
            yearly: 'on the',
            monthly: 'on',
            end: ['Never', 'On date'],
            weekStartsOnSunday: true,
            hideError: true,
          }}
        />
        <TextInput label="Recurrences" source="recurrences" value={state} />
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
```

Use a state object like this

Comment: I tried to use your code but it gives me the error:

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.

And I use it inside the export const Create = props => (
...
<TextInput label="Recurrences" source="recurrences" />
)

Comment: Your trying to use it in a class, to use inside a class you need to use this.setState() rather than a hook state object

Comment: Can you provide an example for it? Thank you. But I using react admin to do it.

Comment: Id suggesting learning how react works before working on it, here is an example of classes vs functions
https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108

Comment: Hi, Sir, I have modified the code to the new one as shown above but I still cannot getting the value from the onChange value when the user choose the recurrences.

Comment: hi, I was able to do it ady, use "defaultValue" instead of "value" and thank you for the solution...